# Mouse Cursor follower Limit to Body

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I currently have [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/dawidvdh/xYJwF/), a dive following the mouse cursor.. but when i come close to the edge of the website it creates scroll bars and such, how would i limit it to stay in the body and hide when its out of veiw rather then extend the website..

Here's the JS;

```
var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
   mouseX = e.pageX;
   mouseY = e.pageY; 
});

// cache the selector
var follower = $("#follower");
var xp = 0, yp = 0;
var loop = setInterval(function(){
    // change 12 to alter damping higher is slower
    xp += (mouseX - xp) / 1;
    yp += (mouseY - yp) / 1;
    follower.css({left:xp+5, top:yp+5});

}, 30);
```

Here's the CSS:

```
#follower{
  position : absolute;
  background-color : red;
  color : white;
  padding : 10px;
}
```

and then the HTML:

```
<div id="follower">Move your mouse</div>
```

Any Help Greatly Appreciated.. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

would could try the following;

```
<div id="mousecontainer" style="position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; overflow: hidden;">
    <div id="follower" />
</div>
```

and then use clientX rather than pageX, so the positions are relative to the screen instead of the page position

EDIT: additionally; add the following to the mousecontainer style:

```
mouse-event: none;
```

this will allow the rest of the page to function as expected

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the overflow property of the containing element to `hidden`

In your fiddle you could add

```
body
{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

to your CSS - http://jsfiddle.net/xYJwF/1/

Comment: But then any expanding content on the web page will be lost? or even longer pages will be lost?

Comment: @DawidvanderHoven But you said you didn't want the page to expand... I don't know about your specific requirements but in your fiddle adding overflow:hidden is an appropriate fix. The point is that you need to have overflow:hidden on the element which contains your moving element. Without knowing your specific requirements it's difficult to help beyond that. :(